# How to update Go's Delve Debugger?

Tags: go, delve

How does one update their Go Delve Debugger? I"m receiving the following error when I try to set the api version:

`unknown flag: --api-version`

My `dlv` looks out of date:

```
$dlv version
Delve Debugger
Version: 0.11.0-alpha
Build:
```

But I can't figure out how to upgrade it. I've tried `go get -u github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv` and `go get -u github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv`, but neither worked. I also tried the suggestion to `make install`:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/go-delve/delve.git $GOPATH/src/github.com/go-delve/delve
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/go-delve/delve
$ make install
```

But that appears to have no effect:

```
$ dlv version
Delve Debugger
Version: 0.11.0-alpha
Build:
```

My go version is `go version go1.10.1 linux/amd64` and my OS details are below:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Release:    8.11
Codename:   jessie
```

This is copied from [the issue](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1512) I opened. I thought I'd cross post for greater visibility.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out @RylanSchaeffer?

Comment: Sadly not. I've since stopped using Go.

Answer (score 8):

You can run `go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest` to install the latest version now.

Note: I'm assuming your problem was related to not setting GOBIN at the time.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem while using goland. After updating goland, i noticed that access was denied to goland updating the dlv file. I was able to fix this by installing goland through snap (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/installation-guide.html#snap). I was also on linux (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when using VSCode with WSL2. I upgraded Go to 1.22 and VSCode would not debug. It threw the same out of date Delve error.

1. Close VSCode.
2. Restart VSCode (this triggered a reinstallation on WSL.)
3. Update go.mod | go entry to read `go 1.22`
4. Rebuild